# Why do I keep getting this error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

the last tab titled contact me does not display any of its content when I click it.

```
<body>
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li data-tab-target="#home" class="active tab">Home</li>
    <li data-tab-target="#pricing" class="tab">Pricing</li>
    <li data-tab-target="#about" class="tab">About</li>
    <li data-tab-target="#Contact Me" class="tab">Contact Me</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" data-tab-content class="active">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>This is the home</p>
    </div>
    <div id="pricing" data-tab-content>
      <h1>Pricing</h1>
      <p>Some information on pricing</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about" data-tab-content>
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>Let me tell you about me</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Contact Me" data-tab-content>
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <p>hello let me tell</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS: This is where the error(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null) is and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]')
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]')

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget)
    tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
      tabContent.classList.remove('active')
    })
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
      tab.classList.remove('active')
    })
    tab.classList.add('active')
    target.classList.add('active')
  
  })
})
```

Comment: Because you make a space in the id - `Contact Me`. Do this - `ContactMe` or `Contact_Me`.

Comment: Which use of `classList` is throwing the error? `tabContent.classlist`, `tab.classList.remove`, `tab.classList.add`, or `target.classList`?

Answer (score 1):

just remove space in `id="Contact Me"`

```
<div id="ContactMe" data-tab-content>
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <p>hello let me tell</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are trying to access the Element before it is loaded.

try wrapping your code in `window.onload`

like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  // paste your whole JS Code here
}
```